# Import Windows Azure Extension Library

Tags: azure

I created my own extension library for Windows Azures Table Storage that supports distributed transactions across entity groups, queues and blobs.  The library works in a Web Role instance but in terms of neatness I would like to put my library into it's own project and then have my web roles and worker roles import this library.  The problem I am having is that I can't get the independant project to recognize

Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient

I have referenced the associated dll

C:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK\v1.6\bin\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll

but still no luck.

So does anyone know how to create their own Azure extender library in a console project that's not in some sort of role?

Comment: Can't you just do this: Select "Add Reference" (from the project menu), and then click on the browse button to locate MicrosoftWindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll. This is how you would link any library to your project: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a reference to the compiled library (and get those imports to work) you would follow these steps:

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click on the project node and click Add
   Reference.
2. In the Add Reference dialog box, select the tab indicating the type
   of component you want to reference.
3. Select the components you want to reference, then click OK.

This documentation references how you would link any library to your project: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.80).aspx

**EDIT:**

Answer from RyanFishman:

*The problem was the target platform which needs to be .net framework 4 instead of .net framework 4 client. Same reason why you couldn't reference System.web in a console application. Instruction on how to set target platform can be found in this link. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx – RyanFishman*

Comment: That works for my other references but not Azure for some reason.

Comment: Did you make sure your reference to the assembly specifies COPY LOCAL?

Comment: I found the problem, The problem was the target platform which needs to be .net framework 4 instead of .net framework 4 client.  Same reason why you couldn't reference System.web in a console application.  Instruction on how to set target platform can be found in this link.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: I updated the answer with your answers. Congrats on finding it out! And be sure to document / publish it if it's really useful... Azure is starting to get big.